# Why is (23 == true) false but (!!23 == true) true? There is === for precise comparison after all

Tags: javascript

All the text is in the title really. I mean both `23` and `true` are truthy, right? So under the lax comparison operator `==` why wouldn't they be equal? There is the precise comparison operator `===` when precision is wanted.

EDIT: I guess in the comments we agreed it is some counter-intuitive bug in the specification.

Comment: Have a look at http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that is a question to the designers of JavaScript and because the answers will be subjective.

Comment: @Markus Jarderot: That table says nothing about numeric values greater than 1.

Comment: Thanks Markus. My question though is: why does it behave as detailed in the table? Note that both `if(23)` and `if(!!23)` evaluate to `true` as you can verify in the `if()` tab of the table you linked. So why is there a difference between `(23 == true)` and `(!!23 == true)`? It isn't consistent

Comment: The language specification is not subjective, there are definite objective answers.

Comment: @Andrei so you are implying there is no reasonal rationale behind it. Well, weird. I was hoping I was just missing it and you guys could show me.

Comment: As I understand, you ask why they invented === instead of relying on some conversions(true => 1). And I think you will not find an answer to that. And PS: I did not downvote your question.

Comment: @hubzkq1 Great question, gave you an upvote. But I think you should give others the chance to answer before selecting an answer.

Comment: @James Wong Thanks James, sorry I was aggressively coerced by the objective crowd to mark an answer fast and final.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first case, `true` is type converted to **numeric** `1` and compared to `23`. Obviously `1 != 23` even though both `1` and `23` would evaluate to `true`.

In the second, `!23` is evaluated to `false`, then `!false` is evaluated as `true` and that is `== true`.

The trick is that the type conversion goes from `boolean` to `numeric` even though it should intuitively be the other way around.

Comment: Right, but why isn't `23` converted to boolean `true` instead? Arbitrary decision by the language designers?

Comment: @hubzkq1 obviously yes. The answer here is the correct one, please mark it. Any discussion of "why would they do that" is subjective and off-topic for the site.

Comment: See also: [wat.mov](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: @hubzkq1 This seems to be an arbitrary decision as you suggest. I would not know what their thinking on the topic was, but it does seem counter-intuitive

Comment: @Niels It is NOT obvious. There might be a good reason which I am (or we both are) missing. My question is about that reason. I will only mark it as correct once the remaining obscurity is satisfactorily resolved.

Comment: @neelsg thanks, and good technical explanation otherwise, so at least it seems counter-intuitive to you too.

Comment: It IS counter intuitive but now explained. Your question is getting downvotes because your question asks for a subjective answer.

Comment: The real answer is probably anchored in javascript's history, but ultimately subjective, speculation and not fitting for this site.

Comment: Alright then..... There could still have been a good reason, but seems like this time there really isn't, fair enough.

Comment: For future reference, see [What types of questions should I avoice asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69595/discussion-between-hubzkq1-and-niels-abildgaard).

Answer (score 1):

When you compare number to boolean, then it casts the boolean to number 1.

> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x ==
>      ToNumber(y).

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: Why not the other way around? Arbitrary decision by the language designers?